# Increase the maximum length and size of a hexadecimal integer in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, hex

I'm using the function `dechex` to convert large decimals to hexadecimal, but I've found that using this function does not serve well for the overly large number. I'm using this process since it seems to be a good compression method for storing large numbers.

The number that I am attempting to hexify is:

```
51501851833710653376097681408
```

And I receive the output:

```
7fffffff // which is 2147483647, the max int
```

I've tried changing the INI:

```
ini_set('PHP_INT_MAX', 0);
```

Which did not change the length of the hexadecimal.

I'm wanting to be able to make the hex maximum of 16-32 characters long. Is this possible without writing a custom hexadecimal algorithm?

From the manual of the function `dechex` it states:

> The largest number that can be converted is PHP_INT_MAX * 2 + 1 (or -1): on 32-bit platforms, this will be 4294967295 in decimal, which results in dechex() returning ffffffff.

Which is understandable, but I still inquire if there is another way around this.

Comment: This is just an idea, so i will comment it instead of posting an answer. The function [`pack()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) might be the solution here. You can then use [`bin2hex()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) to transform it into a hex number string.

Comment: `PHP_INT_MAX` is a constant that defines the maximum integer of your environment, this is not something you can alter, its a hard limit.

Comment: Question: what is the problem you are trying to solve? you say "*good compression method for storing large numbers*"

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php#21086 I found this comment by "joost at" `dec2hex( '51501851833710653376097681408' )`

Answer (score 0):

`int` (and `PHP_INT_MAX` constant) is [platform-specific](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#example-41) and corresponds to `long signed int` C type.

I think you should use some kind of [arbitrary precision base converter](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=arbitrary%20precision%20base%20convert%20php&t=ffsb&ia=software) library or [GMP extension](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-strval.php), PHP has no arbitrary precision arithmetics built in.